# C++ vector segmentation fault causes crash if vector is called

Tags: c++, qt, vector, crash, widget

I am new and really unexperienced with coding, but we got a task at the university where I ran into a problem I could not solve by myself. In one class a vector causes a problem I do not understand. After hours of trial and error I am a bit tired of guessing... So, I try it here and hope for some help.

The program is supposed to draw an diagram based on some Input variables the user can change. At the moment I am trying to implement the painting of the graph. The Input and the calculation of the data works.

One aspect of the task is that we have to safe the calculated data in a vector and pass this vector as a pointer to other functions, for example the painter.

Now, here the problem occures. Any interaction with the vector m_punkte I passed to paintEvent causes a crash of the program. I could narrow the problem down to commands like: vector->begin() or vector->end(). In the instant the program tries to execute them, windows stops the program.

At first I thought the vector could be somehow passed wrong and I am trying to call an empty vector or the address is undefined, but even commands like vector->emty() causing the crash. So I believe it is a more general error which is caused by the framework or something like that.

After running the debugging tool, it also told me that the error is caused by the mentioned commands and further more told me this:

> Der Prozess wurde wegen eines Signals vom Betriebssystem angehalten.
> Name des Signals : SIGSEGV
> Bedeutung : Segmentation fault

I guess that's some kind of memory problem, right?

I would be really happy if someone could help me, so I can work again on the actual task and not guessing why this vector is somehow broken

What I can also tell is that I am working with Qt Creator and the program is running as an QtWidget program if that helps.

Dropbox link to a copy of the programm:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l5e220lk5y7jx2z/AAAdG7AjHiiKJxOKWT-zrP8ia?dl=0

I Hope now my question is clear and this helps more to find the origin of the error.

datenpunkt.h

```
#ifndef DATENPUNKT_H
#define DATENPUNKT_H

#include <vector>

struct datenpunkt
{
        float temperatur;
        float widerstand;
        float laenge;
};
typedef std::vector<datenpunkt> PunktVektor;

#endif // DATENPUNKT_H
```

diagrammwidget.h

```
#ifndef DIAGRAMMWIDGET_H
#define DIAGRAMMWIDGET_H

#include "datenpunkt.h"
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class DiagrammWidget;
}

class DiagrammWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DiagrammWidget( QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DiagrammWidget();

    void setPunkte (PunktVektor *punkte);

    void setUntere_temp(int untere_temp);
    void setObere_temp(int obere_temp);
    void setAufloesung(int aufloesung);

    PunktVektor *punkte() const;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::DiagrammWidget *ui;
    PunktVektor *m_punkte;

    int m_untere_temp = 0;
    int m_obere_temp = 0;
    int m_aufloesung = 0;
};

#endif // DIAGRAMMWIDGET_H
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include "datenpunkt.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    void werteberechnung(PunktVektor *m_PunktListe);

    float untere_temp() const;
    void setUntere_temp(float untere_temp);

    float obere_temp() const;
    void setObere_temp(float obere_temp);

    int aufloesung() const;
    void setAufloesung(int aufloesung);

    QString werkstoff() const;
    void setWerkstoff(QString werkstoff);

    float materialkonstante() const;
    void setMaterialkonstante(float materialkonstante);

    float bezugswiderstand() const;
    void setBezugswiderstand(float bezugswiderstand);

    float wiederstand() const;
    void setWiederstand(float wiederstand);

    float temperatur() const;
    void setTemperatur(float temperatur);

private slots:
    void on_speichern_clicked();
    void on_verwerfen_clicked();
    void on_zuruecksetzen_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    PunktVektor *m_PunktListe;

    QString m_werkstoff = "A 34-2/30 (SIEMENS)";
    float m_materialkonstante = 3440;               // B/ K
    float m_bezugswiderstand = 5000;                // Rto/ Ohm
    float m_untere_temp = 0 + 272.15;
    float m_obere_temp = 300 + 272.15;
    int m_aufloesung = 10;

    float m_RT= 0;                            // Rt/ Ohm
    float m_To = 20 + 272.15;
    float m_T = 0;                             // T/ C°
    float m_UD;         //Untere Dekadengrenze
    float m_OD;         //Obere Dekadengrenze

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

diagrammwidget.cpp

```
#include "diagrammwidget.h"
#include "ui_diagrammwidget.h"
#include "datenpunkt.h"

#include <vector>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

DiagrammWidget::DiagrammWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DiagrammWidget){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_punkte = 0;
}
DiagrammWidget::~DiagrammWidget(){
    delete ui;
}
void DiagrammWidget::setPunkte(PunktVektor *punkte){
    m_punkte = punkte;
}
void DiagrammWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter myPainter (this);
    /*if((m_punkte == 0|| m_punkte->size() == 0)){
        myPainter.drawText(100,100,"No Points found!");
        return;
    }*/
    datenpunkt ersterPunkt=*m_punkte->begin();
    datenpunkt startPunkt = ersterPunkt;
    PunktVektor::iterator it;
    for( it = m_punkte->begin()++; it != m_punkte->end(); it++){
        datenpunkt p = *it;


        myPainter.drawLine(startPunkt.temperatur,startPunkt.laenge,                 
        p.temperatur,p.laenge);
        startPunkt = p;
        }
    }
    PunktVektor *DiagrammWidget::punkte() const{
        return m_punkte;
    }
    void DiagrammWidget::setAufloesung(int aufloesung){
        m_aufloesung = aufloesung;
    }
    void DiagrammWidget::setObere_temp(int obere_temp){
        m_obere_temp = obere_temp;
    }
    void DiagrammWidget::setUntere_temp(int untere_temp){
        m_untere_temp = untere_temp;
    }
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "datenpunkt.h"
#include "diagrammwidget.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QString>
#include <math.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_PunktListe = new PunktVektor;

    //Standarteinstellungen
    ui->werkstoff->setText("A 34-2/30 (SIEMENS)");
    ui->materialkonstante->setValue(3440);
    ui->materialkonstante->setSuffix(" K");
    ui->bezugswiderstand->setValue(5000);
    ui->bezugswiderstand->setSuffix(" Ω");
    ui->unteretemperatur->setValue(0);
    ui->unteretemperatur->setSuffix(" °C");
    ui->oberetemperatur->setValue(300);
    ui->oberetemperatur->setSuffix(" °C");
    ui->aufloesung->setValue(10);
    ui->aufloesung->setSuffix(" Δ°C");

    ui->unteretemperatur->setMaximum(ui->oberetemperatur->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setMinimum(ui->unteretemperatur->value());
    ui->unteretemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());

    werteberechnung(m_PunktListe);

    //Diagramm aktualisieren und Anzeigen
    DiagrammWidget dg;
    dg.setUntere_temp(m_untere_temp);
    dg.setObere_temp(m_obere_temp);
    dg.setAufloesung(m_aufloesung);
    dg.setPunkte(m_PunktListe);
    dg.show();
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete m_PunktListe;
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::werteberechnung(PunktVektor *m_PunktListe)
{
    datenpunkt p;
    float temp = m_untere_temp;

    //Anzahl der zu bestimmenden Datenpunkte
    int anzahl = (m_obere_temp-m_untere_temp)/m_aufloesung;

    //Bestimmen der Dekadengrenzen UD und OD
    m_RT = m_bezugswiderstand * pow(M_E, (m_materialkonstante*         
((1/m_obere_temp)-(1/m_To))));
    m_UD = (int(log10(m_RT)));
    m_RT = m_bezugswiderstand * pow(M_E, (m_materialkonstante*     
((1/m_untere_temp)-(1/m_To))));
    m_OD = (int(log10(m_RT))+1);

    //Füllen des Datenvectors
    for (int i = 0; i <= anzahl; i++){
        m_RT = m_bezugswiderstand * pow(M_E, (m_materialkonstante* 
((1/temp)-(1/m_To))));
        p.widerstand = m_RT;
        p.temperatur = temp;
        float x = log10(m_RT);
        if(m_UD != 0){
            p.laenge = ((x-m_UD)*5);
        }
        else
            p.laenge = x*5;

        m_PunktListe->push_back(p);
        temp = temp + m_aufloesung;
    }
}

void Dialog::on_speichern_clicked()
{
    setWerkstoff(ui->werkstoff->text());
    setMaterialkonstante(ui->materialkonstante->value());
    setBezugswiderstand(ui->bezugswiderstand->value());
    setUntere_temp(ui->unteretemperatur->value()+ 272.15);
    setObere_temp(ui->oberetemperatur->value()+ 272.15);
    setAufloesung(ui->aufloesung->value());

    ui->unteretemperatur->setMaximum(ui->oberetemperatur->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setMinimum(ui->unteretemperatur->value());
    ui->unteretemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());

    //Berechnung des Datenvectors
    werteberechnung(m_PunktListe);

    //Diagramm aktualisieren
    DiagrammWidget dg;
    dg.setUntere_temp(m_untere_temp);
    dg.setObere_temp(m_obere_temp);
    dg.setAufloesung(m_aufloesung);
    dg.setPunkte(m_PunktListe);
    dg.show();
}

float Dialog::temperatur() const{
    return m_T;
}
void Dialog::setTemperatur(float temperatur){
    m_T = temperatur;
}
float Dialog::wiederstand() const{
    return m_RT;
}
void Dialog::setWiederstand(float wiederstand){
    m_RT = wiederstand;
}
float Dialog::bezugswiderstand() const{
    return m_bezugswiderstand;
}
void Dialog::setBezugswiderstand(float bezugswiderstand){
    m_bezugswiderstand = bezugswiderstand;
}
float Dialog::materialkonstante() const{
    return m_materialkonstante;
}
void Dialog::setMaterialkonstante(float materialkonstante){
    m_materialkonstante = materialkonstante;
}
QString Dialog::werkstoff() const{
    return m_werkstoff;
}
void Dialog::setWerkstoff(QString werkstoff){
    m_werkstoff = werkstoff;
}
int Dialog::aufloesung() const{
    return m_aufloesung;
}
void Dialog::setAufloesung(int aufloesung){
m_aufloesung = aufloesung;
}
float Dialog::obere_temp() const{
    return m_obere_temp;
}
void Dialog::setObere_temp(float obere_temp){
    m_obere_temp = obere_temp;
}
float Dialog::untere_temp() const
{
    return m_untere_temp;
}
void Dialog::setUntere_temp(float untere_temp)
{
    m_untere_temp = untere_temp;
}
void Dialog::on_verwerfen_clicked()
{
    ui->werkstoff->setText(m_werkstoff);
    ui->materialkonstante->setValue(m_materialkonstante);
    ui->bezugswiderstand->setValue(m_bezugswiderstand);
    ui->unteretemperatur->setValue(m_untere_temp);
    ui->oberetemperatur->setValue(m_obere_temp);
    ui->aufloesung->setValue(m_aufloesung);

    ui->unteretemperatur->setMaximum(ui->oberetemperatur->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setMinimum(ui->unteretemperatur->value());
    ui->unteretemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());
}

void Dialog::on_zuruecksetzen_clicked()
{
    //Standarteinstellungen
    ui->werkstoff->setText("A 34-2/30 (SIEMENS)");
    ui->materialkonstante->setValue(3440);
    ui->bezugswiderstand->setValue(5000);
    ui->unteretemperatur->setValue(0);
    ui->aufloesung->setValue(10);
    ui->oberetemperatur->setValue(300);

    setWerkstoff(ui->werkstoff->text());
    setMaterialkonstante(ui->materialkonstante->value());
    setBezugswiderstand(ui->bezugswiderstand->value());
    setUntere_temp(ui->unteretemperatur->value()+ 272.15);
    setObere_temp(ui->oberetemperatur->value()+ 272.15);
    setAufloesung(ui->aufloesung->value());

    ui->unteretemperatur->setMaximum(ui->oberetemperatur->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setMinimum(ui->unteretemperatur->value());
    ui->unteretemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());
    ui->oberetemperatur->setSingleStep(ui->aufloesung->value());

    werteberechnung(m_PunktListe);

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Willkommen in Stack Overflow. We ask that you provide [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of misbehaving code. In practice, this means that you should pare your code down as far as you can while still recreating the crash. This makes the code easier for us to study (z.b. I do not have QWidgets, so I cannot recreate the error), and it improves your chance of finding the bug without our help. More generally, it is a good idea to write code by starting with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity in small stages.

Comment: Don't use a pointer. Use a simple vector `PunktVektor m_punkte`.

Comment: thx for the quic answer ! I will try to do next time better with the documentation. Due to the fact that i have to use a pointer to pass the vector I can not do much aboud it. Further I am a bit iritated that is does not work, cause i made a fairly simmilar class where it made no problems. The error is triggered at the moment where the code calles the m_punkte in paintEvent. I cutted all the other code out of the paintEvent function to the point where only these lines left. That is the reason I am presenting them it like that. The other code had not made differens.

Comment: You do not need to use a pointer, you could just as easily use a reference. If you insist on a pointer then code that is important is the code that creates the vector and passes the pointer to `setPunkte`, and that is exactly the code you have not included. You'll need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote... voting up.

Comment: `*m_punkte->empty();` the code could be compiled?

Comment: ok, I will edit my question so its better to understand. Mybe it was a bit rushed at the evening.

Comment: @Jiu no ->empty also causes a crash. As far as I tested all common vector function causing the crash as long I am calling the vector m_punkte in paintEvent

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, your example is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But guessing, there are a couple of clues:

```
PunktVektor *m_punkte;         //This is the mentioned vector
```

and

```
datenpunkt test = *m_punkte->begin();    <-            //The programm crashs
```

Unless `PunktVector` overloads `operator->()`, your access of the vector should probably be

```
datenpunkt test = m_punkte->begin();    <-            //no dereference (*)
```

REVISION:
With your updated example, the basic problem is dereferencing the `end()` iterator, which is a marker and does not refer to an element

```
    datenpunkt test = *m_punkte->begin(); 
    datenpunkt test2 =*m_punkte->end();
    *m_punkte->empty();
```

`m_punkte->begin()` returns an iterator to the first element (if there is one; the vector could be empty). `*( m_punkte->begin() )` accesses the element the iterator refers to.
`m_punkte->end()` return an iterator marking the end of the container. `* (m_punkte->end() )` is undefined.
`m_punkte->empty()` returns a `bool` reflecting whether the container is empty or not. `*( m_punkte->empty() )` will access either memory location `0` or `1` (both of which are likely to be very bad.

REVISION 2:
When working with containers, it is important to understand how you can hurt yourself. In particular, look here:

```
void DiagrammWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter myPainter (this);
    /*if((m_punkte == 0|| m_punkte->size() == 0)){
        myPainter.drawText(100,100,"No Points found!");
        return;
    }*/
    datenpunkt ersterPunkt=*m_punkte->begin();
    datenpunkt startPunkt = ersterPunkt;
    PunktVektor::iterator it;
    for( it = m_punkte->begin()++; it != m_punkte->end(); it++){
        datenpunkt p = *it;

        myPainter.drawLine(startPunkt.temperatur,startPunkt.laenge,                 
            p.temperatur,p.laenge);
        startPunkt = p;
    }
}
```

If you are going to do this: `datenpunkt ersterPunkt=*m_punkte->begin();`
 then you must first check to see of the container is empty.

`Container.begin()` returns an iterator to the first element of the container. If the container is empty, this iterator is equal to `Container.end()`. Dereferencing this iterator is a good way to crash your program.

Try refactoring your program like this:

```
void DiagrammWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter myPainter (this);
    if( m_punkte == nullptr || m_punkte->empty() ){
    //    myPainter.drawText(100,100,"No Points found!");
        return;
    }
    auto startPunkt = m_punkte->begin();
    for( auto it = ++(m_punkte->begin()); it != m_punkte->end(); ++it){
        auto const& p = *it;

        myPainter.drawLine(startPunkt->temperatur,startPunkt->laenge,                 
            p.temperatur,p.laenge);
        startPunkt = it;
    }
}
```

You see that this properly protects against your allowed condition of a null pointer or an empty container before making assumptions about the contents of the container. It also uses iterators as intended, rather than making unnecessary copies of the elements of the container.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the worked out answer!  I tried to access the vector without the (*), but get then a conversion error.  But I think my original question was a bit missleading. I have updated the question now. Maybe its now more clear what my problem is...

Comment: please post the exact error you are getting. Us trying to guess your mistakes is not productive. Also, consider the comment by @Retired Ninja ... there is no reason for the vector to be a pointer.

Comment: Ok, that looks convenient. That's really helpful! But why is then the vector empty ? If I try for example to print out the vector in setPunkte in the console, it shows up...

Comment: I would suggest that you use your debugger to step through your program and find out exactly why it is crashing. The example is still far from minimal.

Comment: It isn't crashing any more. But now the m_punkte vector is allways identified as an nullptr in the paintEvent class. I can read m_punkte anywhere else except there. Maybe that's a dum question, but why is it doing that? I dont get it.